# WordPress not recognizing simple Javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, api, linkedin-api

Okay, so I've uploaded this *super* simple HTML page here:

http://medicaldevicesgroup.net/wp-content/themes/medicaldevicesgroup/test.html

It's utilizing LinkedIn's "Sign In" API. View the source. It's two lines of code. Nothing.

BUT

I created a home.php file in my child theme directory, and pasted this:

```
<?php require(CHILD_DIR.'/test.html'); ?>
```

This means that if you view the source at http://www.medicaldevicesgroup.net/, it's EXACTLY the same as the source at http://medicaldevicesgroup.net/wp-content/themes/medicaldevicesgroup/test.html. The only difference is that the home page is in WordPress, and the other URL isn't.

The home page script, however, doesn't work. WHY???? Help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the LinkedIn API that you are using is for  `http://medicaldevicesgroup.net` and not `http://www.medicaldevicesgroup.net`. Notice the "www" in 2nd URL. You need to change your URL in the LinkedIn API.

To see what I mean try going to http://www.medicaldevicesgroup.net/wp-content/themes/medicaldevicesgroup/test.html and it will not work there too.